# svn setup permission issues

Tags: linux, svn

I'm having trouble setting up my svn. I used apt-get install subversion to install the software. The default svn folder was /home/svn/ I changed the ownership of the folder to an administrator account (not root) and a subversion user group I setup. I set the folder permissions to 0760 recursively through all the subfolders.

Yet whenever I try connecting to the repo I get this: "Commit failed (details follow):
Can't open file '/home/svn/bftc/format': Permission denied".

I have no idea what's wrong!

Comment: Try "apt-get install git" instead. :P

Comment: It is probably more usefull to give information on your linux distribution than on which program you are trying to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your user has execute permission on any folder.  770 should work for you (as Newton Falls pointed out) as this will allow group execute.

Comment: I'll give 0770 a try soon, but I'm pretty sure I woud have tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

If your svn repository is owned by a group that you are not in, then 770 will not work. You have to be part of the group, or change permissions to 777. The former is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

How have you set up the repository access? Does your user have permissions to access your repository? If it is via the svn access file you may want to check the user permissions.

Comment: Yes, everything is setup according to an Ubuntu svn setup guide I used. I've google'd it and some people have a similar issue with my error but when I apply their suggestions to patch it still doesn't work.